# How can I get this to work, I'm trying to import a git command

Tags: git, powershell

git : The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- git clone https://github.com/HashLips/hashlips_art_engine.git
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (git:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: That's PowerShell's way of saying "I could not find `git`". Like the old joke about showing the printer to your computer, just saying "it's installed" isn't going to help: you will need to tell PowerShell (however that's done) where to look.

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out? I'm having the same issue. Git works in Command Prompt and every Git GUI I've tried, just not Powershell. Both bin and cmd paths show up in $env:path. I also have a Git module in one of my $env:PSModulePath locations. Reinstallation and restart didn't fix it. Really bizarre.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you don't have git installed or you don't have git added in your path variable. there is a tutorial is this site https://code2care.org/q/powershell-git--the-term-git-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet .

Comment: I've already been to this website and tried all 3 options.

Comment: This error probably happens when you don't have git installed properly.

Comment: I know that's the issue I'm just not sure how to fix it.